# Navigation Bar Heading Text Positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar that will expand when the mouse is over it. I wish to display heading text once it is expanded (currently shows icons), I have used `display: none` on the heading tag, which then toggles to `display: inline-block` when the `:hover` event is active on the navbar. However, upon expansion of the navbar the text renders in on two lines before positioning itself into one which I want. I want to get rid of this and have the text render in as one line only while the navbar expands. My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Navigation Bar</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6cc49d804e.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="sidenav">
      <div id="sidenav-brand">
        <div id="sidenav-heading">
          <h2>Expanded Test</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="sidenav-expand">
          <i id="expand-icon" class="fas fa-angle-double-right fa-2x"></i>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="sidenav-links">
        <ul id="links">
          <li>
            <i class="fas fa-fw fa-id-card fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
          <li>
            <i class="fas fa-fw fa-graduation-cap fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
          <li>
            <i class="fas fa-fw fa-briefcase fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
          <li>
            <i class="fas fa-fw fa-smile-beam fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
}

/* Make the width full-size then use javascript to minimise so content fits */
#sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1e1e2d;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: grey;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

#sidenav-brand {
  padding: 25px 20px;
  background-color: #1a1a27;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#sidenav-heading {
  display: none;
}

#sidenav-heading h2 {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

#sidenav-expand {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

#expand-icon {
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

#sidenav:hover {
  width: 280px;
}

#sidenav:hover #expand-icon {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#sidenav:hover #sidenav-heading {
  display: inline-block;
}

#sidenav-links {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

#links {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

#links li {
  padding: 18px;
  display: block;
}

#links li:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: hotpink;
}

.fas {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Please check this fiddle for what I mean when the navbar expands:
https://jsfiddle.net/4pk25oLh/

P.S. The effect I want is the same as when you get rid of the space in the heading text (however, I will need the space). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using display property, you can create a cool fade animation for that.
First, add `white-space: nowrap` to the `<h2>`, so the text will not wrap.
Then, you use properties such as visiblity, opacity, max-width and transition to create the effect.

```
body {
}

/* Make the width full-size then use javascript to minimise so content fits */
#sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1e1e2d;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: grey;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

#sidenav-brand {
  padding: 25px 20px;
  background-color: #1a1a27;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#sidenav-heading {
  display: inline-block;
}

#sidenav-heading h2 {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 0;
  transition: 0.16s;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#sidenav-expand {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

#expand-icon {
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

#sidenav:hover {
  width: 280px;
}

#sidenav:hover #expand-icon {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#sidenav:hover #sidenav-heading h2 {
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 100vw;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: 0.4s 0.5s;
}

#sidenav-links {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

#links {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

#links li {
  padding: 18px;
  display: block;
}

#links li:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: hotpink;
}

.fas {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `white-space: nowrap;` might help.

```
 #sidenav-heading h2 {
      margin: 0;
      color: white;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update below CSS selectors in your style file or CSS:

```css
             body {
                  }

            /* Make the width full-size then use javascript to minimise so content fits */
            #sidenav {
              height: 100%;
              width: 75px;
              position: fixed;
              z-index: 1;
              top: 0;
              left: 0;
              background-color: #1e1e2d;
              overflow-x: hidden;
              color: grey;
              transition: width 0.5s;
            }

            #sidenav-brand {
              padding: 25px 20px;
              background-color: #1a1a27;
              display: flex;
              flex-direction: row;
              justify-content: flex-end;
              align-items: center;
            }

            #sidenav-heading {
              display: inline-block;
              position: absolute;
              width: 240px;
              left: 20px;
              transition: opacity 0.3s;
              -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
              opacity: 0;
            }

            #sidenav-heading h2 {
              margin: 0;
              color: white;
            }

            #sidenav-expand {
              text-align: center;
              margin-left: 3px;
            }

            #expand-icon {
              transition: transform 0.5s;
            }

            #sidenav:hover {
              width: 280px;
            }

            #sidenav:hover #expand-icon {
              transform: rotate(180deg);
            }

            #sidenav:hover #sidenav-heading {
              opacity: 1;
            }

            #sidenav-links {
              margin: 15px 0;
            }

            #links {
              list-style-type: none;
              padding: 0;
              text-align: left;
            }

            #links li {
              padding: 18px;
              display: block;
            }

            #links li:hover {
              color: white;
              background-color: hotpink;
            }

            .fas {
              vertical-align: middle;
            }
```

```html
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6cc49d804e.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
<div id="sidenav">
      <div id="sidenav-brand">
        <div id="sidenav-heading">
          <h2>Expanded Test</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="sidenav-expand">
          <i id="expand-icon" class="fas fa-angle-double-right fa-2x"></i>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="sidenav-links">
        <ul id="links">
          <li>
            <i class="fas fa-fw fa-id-card fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
          <li>
            <i class="fas fa-fw fa-graduation-cap fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
          <li>
            <i class="fas fa-fw fa-briefcase fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
          <li>
            <i class="fas fa-fw fa-smile-beam fa-2x"></i>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```